# XmlElement Error Jabber-net Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xmpp

When the code is compiled the error is show:

```
using System.Xml;

void _Cliente_OnMessage(object sender, jabber.protocol.client.Message msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(msg.Body);
    }
```

error:

> Error 1   The type 'System.Xml.XmlElement' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.    C:\Users\Julio\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WorkChat\WorkChat\MainActivity.cs  94  14  WorkChat

Comment: You should post the actual code and the actual error message - not a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of mono is not supporting c# library. So that you should have to use jabber-net to work with chat in any of the platform. Here is a link to download jabber-net open source code: https://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/downloads/list

I faced the same issue you are facing. i spent 5-6 days to resolve this issue but the final resolution is to place source code into the solution instead of the any .dll file.

Also let me know if you have any single query regarding the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling Jabber-Net yourself, rather than using the precompiled version.

Comment: I have compiled for the Net Framework 4.0., but now the value of the version field, moved to 4.0.0.0. Properties in the System.Xml appears with the version v2.0.50727